# Alternatives to "says quickly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

What are some alternatives to "says quickly"?

Comment: *Rattle off* "Say, perform, or produce something quickly and effortlessly: *he rattled off some instructions* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rattle

Answer (score 3):

"Blurts out," comes to mind first. Depends on if the "quickly" is frantic or hushed. "Spills" might also work. A little more detail to the sentence or usage would help.

Comment: Support it with an authentic source to show why it is suitable for the OP's context.

Answer (score 0):

To [gabble](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gabble) may also suggest the idea, especially if you are referring  to a quick and indistinctive way of speaking.

> - To speak rapidly or incoherently; jabber.

(TFD)